# Shortening Custom Document Property additions

Tags: vba, excel

### Context

I have blocks of if statements that check if a certain cell contains a particular string and to add to the counter of the respective custom property. Originally I was using global variables, but those are zeroed out when excel crashes. I learned of custom document properties and their non-volatility and made the switch. However, adding to the counter is a long, barely readable statement.

With global variables I had a statement like:

```
If cell = "Heavy Duty" Then numHD = numHD + 4
```

But now statements look like:

```
If cell = "Heavy Duty" Then ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("numHD").Value = ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("numHD").Value + 4
```

It's immensely longer and with 27 other statements doing the same thing for other strings, the code becomes taxing to read.

### What I would like

Is there a way that I can shorten the custom document property edits to look more in line with what I had before with global variables? I had tried setting up a global variable as a properties type and setting to the property, then just using the variable in the actual sub:

```
Public numHD As Properties
Set numHD = ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("numHD")

Sub count()
    If cell = "Heavy Duty" Then numHD = numHD + 4
End Sub
```

But Set cannot be used outside of a sub or function apparently. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to a document property is a concern in its own right, and thus deserves its own scope. Write a procedure that's responsible only for this!

```
Public Sub IncrementHeavyDutyCount(ByVal increment As Long)
    With ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Item("numHD")
        .Value = .Value + increment
    End With
End Sub
```

And now you can increment your counter with a simple, self-explanatory procedure call:

```
If cell = "Heavy Duty" Then IncrementHeavyDutyCount 4
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what makes writing to a document property a concern? Maybe I'm misunderstanding something. All of my research, which admittedly was quite some time ago, pointed to this being the best route.

Comment: @LuxClaridge rather hard to explain when all context I have is a single line of code from your project, but as a general rule of thumb, adhering to the *Single Responsibility Principle* means writing small procedures that are responsible for as little as possible - a procedure that does one thing, only has one reason to fail. In this case, "index out of range" if there's no `"numHD"` custom property in `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: My own approach when wanting to "save" application-specific values within a workbook is to create an "ApplicationData" worksheet and store all my data there. Quite often, I'll make that worksheet `hidden` (and sometimes `veryhidden`). Data on a worksheet is automatically persistent storage in this respect. So while in the distant past I researched the possibility of using document properties, I've never had the need for them.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Oh now I understand. Thanks!